# Based on first Sorting, Sort again Sqlite vs Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, data-structures

Combine Multiple Sqlite Query

**Database Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `userdetails` ( `_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `username` TEXT NOT NULL, `code` TEXT NOT NULL, `usertype` TEXT NOT NULL, `userID` TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`_id`) )
```

```
_id   username code  usertype  userID  
"1"   "user1"  "ERE" "type1"   "1"  
"2"   "user2"  "ERE" "type2"   "2"  
"3"   "user1"  "ERE" "type3"   "3"  
"4"   "user1"  "ERE" "type4"   "4"  
"5"   "user2"  "ERE" "type1"   "5"  
"6"   "user2"  "ERE" "type2"   "6"  
"7"   "user2"  "ERE" "type4"   "7"  
"8"   "user2"  "ERE" "type3"   "8"  
"9"   "user2"  "ERE" "type5"   "9"  
"10"  "user2"  "ERE" "type1"   "10"  
"11"  "user2"  "ERE" "type2"   "11"
```

I'm writing this in SQLite Query in Android Application

output should be
Highest userID value will have some user type, all that usertype should be there, followed by next highest value.... see example

```
"11" "user2" "ERE" "type2" "11"
"6"  "user2" "ERE" "type2" "6"      
"2"  "user2" "ERE" "type2" "2"  

"10" "user2" "ERE" "type1" "10"  
"5"  "user2" "ERE" "type1" "5"  
"1"  "user1" "ERE" "type1" "1"  

"9"  "user2" "ERE" "type5" "9"  

"8"  "user2" "ERE" "type3" "8"  
"3"  "user1" "ERE" "type3" "3"  

"7"  "user2" "ERE" "type4" "7"  
"4"  "user1" "ERE" "type4" "4"
```

I tried this but didn't work as expected

```
SELECT *  FROM userdetails  ORDER BY usertype <> (SELECT usertype FROM userdetails ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1), _id DESC;
```

Is it worth to write this query or It is better to to do this logic in andoird java file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the highest userID value per type, use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT usertype,
       MAX(userID) AS highestID
FROM userdetails
GROUP BY usertype;
```

You can then join this with the original table so that that value is available for each row:

```sql
SELECT userdetails.*
FROM userdetails
JOIN (SELECT usertype,
             MAX(userID) AS highestIDperType
      FROM userdetails
      GROUP BY usertype
     ) USING (usertype)
ORDER BY highestIDperType DESC,
         userID DESC;
```